# Nuget libraries are 'available' in one framework and not another, build crashes out on either

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, namespaces, nuget

I'm writing some nuget packages for personal development, and I'm having a few issues with dependencies. I'm writing a security package and I need `System.Security.Cryptography`, but when I add a using statement for it, I get a weird error about it being available in `.NET Framework 4.5.1`, but not available in `.NET platform 5.4`. It's telling me to use the navigation bar to swap between them, which I am doing, but when I build in either version, it throws an error about the namespace `System.Security.Cryptography` being unavailable. I've tried adding a reference in the `project.json`, but I can't find the current version information for it.

UPDATE: VS says all my classes and namespaces etc. are available in Framework 4.5.1, but when I build it breaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution was to add a reference to the namespace in the `project.json`. The package is then restored and you're good to go.